# C reset strtok on certain condition

Tags: c

I want to read lines of a file and then use the values to do certain actions. However how can I reset the pointer of line/value so it reads the next instance till ';' ?

I am trying to read the following line:

```
Roatan;57-114;250-500;125-375;34-85;68-170;40-80;85-170;100-200;450-900;30-60;34-85;170-340;57-114;500-1000;23-57
```

I am using the following code to do this:

```
char line[400];
int count = 0;

FILE *file;
file = fopen("assets/goederen hoeveelheid.csv", "r");

while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
    if (count > 6) {
        char* goods[50];
        int counter = 0;
        Goods* gameGoods = NULL;
        Harbor* harbor = NULL;

        char* value = strtok(line, ";");

        while (value != NULL)
        {
            goods[counter] = value;

            if (counter > 0) {
                harbor = game->getHarbor(hashHarbors(goods[0]));
                gameGoods = harbor->addGoods(getGoods(counter));

                char* amount = strtok(value, "-");
                int minAmount = atoi(amount);
                int maxAmount = -1;
                amount = strtok(NULL, "-");

                if (amount != NULL)
                {
                    maxAmount = atoi(amount);
                }

                if (minAmount > -1 && maxAmount > -1) {
                    gameGoods->setAmountsAtHarbor(getGoods(counter), minAmount, maxAmount);
                }                   
            }

            value = strtok(NULL, ";");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    count++;
}

fclose(file);
```

So the program has to be like the following: read a line from the file, read the first instance till ';' and store it in goods[counter] then read the next instance till ';' get the number before the '-' and then after. Next, read the next instance till ';'.

Comment: Just alternate the delimeter on subsequent calls of strtok. See the manual.

Comment: ...and call strtok with null for the string on subsequent calls. Again, see the manual.

Comment: Note that in `goods[counter] = value;` the value of `value` is not copied and `value` is reused with every line read.